# Rails + Cucumber + Selenium: How to click on a span inside a ul and li?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write tests for clicking around on my mobile site. However, I'm having trouble finding any documentation on how to click embedded non link elements. This is my HTML:

```
form id="search-results-form" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <ul id="see-more-search" class="see-more" style="display: block; height: auto;">
            <li>
                 <span>Color</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <span>Width</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 ...
```

This is my incomplete cucumber test:

```
When(/^touch "Color"$/) do
  within(:css, '#see-more-search') do
    #I want to be able to click the span with the text 'Color', but
    #don't know how to target it from this point
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how I would target the first `li` or the 'Color' span?

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript:

```
page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{ $('#see-more-search ul li:first').trigger("mouseenter").click(); }
```

Comment: there's no error now, but it doesn't trigger my javascript hide/show, which I need it to do for the next action.